# How to install H265 on 15.10?

Tags: gpu-driver

How to install H265 on 15.10?

I tried

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libde265
```

but I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer1.0-libde265
E: Couldn't find any package by regex "gstreamer1.0-libde265"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~strukturag/+archive/ubuntu/libde265) it is only covered up to Vivid 15.04.  You can still download it, but you need to make a change to the PPA file on your system.

The reason for changing it, when you add a repository with the `add-apt-repository`, it creates a PPA based on your distro of Ubuntu that you have.  The distro you have is code named `Wily` for Ubuntu 15.10.  So, the file created for the PPA which should be, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/strukturag-libde265-wily.list`, contains the following line:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu wily main
```

so during a `sudo apt-get update` you should have seen something like this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The way to fix it for now would be to change the line in the file for one step back for the PPA so you can install the desired H264 files.

To modify the PPA file for now, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up a run window.  Then type in the following to edit:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/strukturag-libde265-wily.list
```

It will ask for your password as this needed elevated level to modify this file.  Then make the following change:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu wily main
```

to

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu vivid main
```

Then you can just close the file as it will prompt you to save it.  Save the changes, then rerun

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libde265
```

**It is not recommended to keep a PPA that does not belong to the version of Ubuntu you are running as it can update applications to the wrong versions made for your distro.**  You should be OK for installing the `gstreamer1.0-libde265`.  After installing, I recommend to go back and modify the PPA file one more time and comment out that line so that it is not part of `sudo apt-get update` until they put out a `Wily` version of the PPA.

To comment out, change

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu vivid main
```

to

```
#deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu vivid main
```

Hope this helps!